# How can i apply a style with x:Key in codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tab.Header = asig.cNombre;
tab.Name = asig.cNombre;
tab.MinWidth = 200;
```

And i have to apply them a style that is located in another file with an x:key

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="TabsVerticales">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./Resources/Fuentes/#Sniglet"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
</Style>
```

How can i do that? 
I saw some posts that said to do something like

```
tab.Style = (Style)FindResource("Resources");
```

but i don't how to get there the x:key.

Thanks!

Comment: *but i don't how to get there the x:key.*, don't you already *know* the key? That's kind of the point of having a key in the first place.

Comment: hopefully your another file is a ResourceDictionary which is also being merged in current file. then only FindResource("TabsVerticales") will work. Is that the case or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the key to the FindResource method like this:

```
tab.Style = (Style)FindResource("TabsVerticales");
```